# Half my circuit breakers are out I tryed resetting them all and reset main breakers

Tags: electrical-panel, power

I used a voltage meter and test them all half show power half do not. Any ideas what the problem may be?

Comment: I'm showing 6 volts on a couple breakers

Comment: Call your utility, you may have dropped a service leg.  If you're comfortable working in the panel, you could test the voltage on the lines feeding the panel.

Answer (score 2):

6 volts with a digital meter could very easily be phantom voltage.

Sounds like you have half your service out. This could be anything from a bad main breaker, problem in the meter pan, the taps at the service drop, or a utility problem at the pole or the service drop itself.

CALL YOUR POWER COMPANY right away, they'll take it from there.

Comment: Thank you I did test it and it shows zero on the voltage meter. So I'm assuming that's what it is then.